# Nuxt: put compile js file to public folder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I need to compile js file for firebase and put this file in a public directory, is it possible? If i just put this file in static I have error "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

I expect that js file will be present in the host root directory and it will be compiled

Comment: Hi, did you tried googling for `Cannot use import statement outside a module`?